# How can I prevent MapKit Annotations from disappearing when panning?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am using Swift's MapKit and custom annotations to place pins on the map. The custom annotations are ZStacks which create a pin with a radius. The `getNearbyEvents` function below returns a list of `Place`'s.

```swift
Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            annotationItems: getNearbyEvents()
        ) {
            place in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate:place.coordinate) {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
                        .frame(width:160, height:160)
                        .opacity(0.6)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color("AccentColor"))
                        .opacity(0.2)
                        .frame(width:160, height:160)
                    Image("MapPin")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
```

When using the preview of the map in the SwiftUI canvas, I can pan around and the experience is pretty smooth. The annotations are always visible and work great, aside from some flickering. However, when I build the application onto my device, the Map will no longer display any of the annotations while panning. They all go invisible until the map comes to a stop. Is there any way to prevent this behavior? I'd like the annotations to be always visible.

Comment: Try .compositingGroup or .drawingGroup modifier on ZStack.

Comment: @Asperi unfortunately, neither of these modifiers worked. I tried `.compositingGroup()`, `.drawingGroup()`, and then tried both in combination, in both orders. No configuration fixed the panning issue. The `.drawingGroup()` modifier also caused the custom annotations to have their edges slightly cropped.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue-- my markers were disappearing when panning or zooming.

I think it was because my annotations (analogous to your "getNearbyEvents()") were in a computed variable and were being updated each time the view was being updated. I solved it by making sure my annotations only calculated once, upon initialization of my view.

This may or may not work for your use case, but hope it helps.

Comment: Nice.  This suggestion worked for me.  Thanks!